# How to find java class dependency tree

Tags: java, compilation

I am trying to pull a bunch of classes and packages from a large project and create a separate standalone module out of it. Now when I try to compile these classes, due to dependency on other classes, I end up with very large number of compiled classes which I don't intend to have in the standalone module. 
e.g. if this is class dependency A -> B -> C -> D. And I compile A, I will end with A.class, B.class, C.class and D.class. I want to break the dependency on class D and refactor the code such that class D doesn't become part of the module. But for this to happen, I would have to know the dependency path(s) for given class A and class D.
I tried searching SO but without success so far.

Answer (score 1):

For future stumble-upons: At least as of IntelliJ 2020.1, you can find the list of classes a class would need (or depend upon), recursively, by:

1. Right click on the class name
2. Click Analyze > Dependencies
3. Choose File .java
4. You can also specify the depth required

(For finding which classes depend on the class in question, choose Analyze > "Backward Dependencies", instead)

For other cases or alternatives: [How do I get a list of Java class dependencies for a main class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200483/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-java-class-dependencies-for-a-main-class)